# Using pipes in an alias

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, alias

I have this in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias jpsdir="jps | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pwdx"
```

but when I use `jpsdir` I get this output:

```
pwdx: invalid process id: JvmName
```

but running

```
jps | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pwdx
```

gives the correct results:

```
1234: /some/dir/
```

What is wrong with my alias? Should i make it a function ?

Comment: Try a function: `jpsdirfn() { jps | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pwdx; }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) has explained in the comments, the reason that your alias wasn't working was because the `$1` in your awk command was being expanded by the shell. The value is likely to be empty, so the awk command becomes `{print }` and `pwdx` is being passed both parts of the output of `jps`.

You can avoid having to escape the `$` by avoiding using awk entirely; you can use the `-q` switch rather than piping to awk:

```
jpsdir() {
    jps -q | xargs pwdx
}
```

I would personally prefer to use a function but you can use an alias if you like.

Comment: Of course pipes can be used in aliases... here the problem is because of the double quotes (since `$1` is very likely unset at the moment where the alias is defined), the alias assignment is equivalent to `alias jpsdir="jps | awk '{print }' | xargs pwdx"` (without `$1`).

Answer (score 0):

Been trying to run : `date | awk '{print $5}'`  as a command to extract the time from the date command.
When I run "time"  as a command, I get this gibberish:

```
time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

So the time is the 5th string item in the date command and I was so pleased when I plucked it out using an awk command, my first attempt at using awk.
As Tom French's answer suggests if you get rid of the $x above, the command prints the entire date string.
It didn't take me very many attempts using the alias command before I came upon a pretty simple example that wouldn't run.

Comment: time is not necessarily the 5th element of a date. It depends on the locale. To get the time run `date` with format parameter like `date +%T`